# Why this function is not showing the correct result as output?

Tags: c, function

The output of this function everytime is:

> The row with minimal sum is 1 whose sum is 0.

But I want it to calculate the sum of each row and then display the min row with its sum.
It displays the correct result if I use this code as a program, and not inside the function(as in this case).

```
void findRowWithMinimalSum(int row, int col, int A[row][col]){
    int i,j,sum,minSum,position;

  for(i=0; i<row; i++){
    printf("\nGive the elements of row %d:\n", i+1);
    for(j=0; j<col; j++)
        scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);
  }

  for(i=0; i<row; i++){
    for(j=0; j<col; j++)
        printf("%d", A[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }

   for(i=0; i<row; i++){
    sum=0;
    for(j=0; j<col; j++){
        sum = sum + A[i][j];
    }
    if(sum<minSum){
        minSum = sum;
        position = i;
    }
   }
   printf("\nThe row with minimal sum is %d whose sum is %d", position+1, minSum);
  }

int main(){
 int row, column, m[50][50];

 //function call
 findRowWithMinimalSum(3,3,m);
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `minSum` is uninitialized. When you try to compare it to `sum`, you'll get undefined behaviour. Initialize it with a high value, eg. INT_MAX.

Comment: to elaborate on the comment from @rcosteira , in C an uninitialized variable takes on the value that just happens to be in the spot in memory that gets reserved for storing that variable; that's why the behavior with uninitialized values is undefined;  in C, it's crucial to initialize variables before relying on their value in your logic;  you will often see, e.g.,  `int qtySocks = 0;`    ... for a `min` value, start with a very large initial value so that your inputs are sure to be less than that;  HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work

```
#include<stdio.h>

void findRowWithMinimalSum(int row, int col, int A[row][col]){
    int i,j,sum,minSum,position;

  for(i=0; i<row; i++){
    printf("\nGive the elements of row %d:\n", i+1);
    for(j=0; j<col; j++)
        scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);
  }

  for(i=0; i<row; i++){
    for(j=0; j<col; j++)
        printf("%d", A[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }

   for(i=0; i<row; i++){
    sum=0;
    for(j=0; j<col; j++){
        sum = sum + A[i][j];
    }


    if(i==0){
        minSum = sum;
        position = i;
    }
    else if(sum<minSum){
        minSum = sum;
        position = i;
    }
   }
   printf("\nThe row with minimal sum is %d whose sum is %d", position+1, minSum);
  }

int main(){
 int row, column, m[50][50];

 //function call
 findRowWithMinimalSum(3,3,m);
  return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Look carefully at `minSum`.  You don't explicitly initialize it before using it in this test:

```
if (sum < minSum)
```

Therefore, if you're running a debug build and it gets initialized to zero, it'll never change unless sum is < 0.

Note that referencing an uninitialized value is undefined behavior, something that should be avoided at all costs.

1. Try this entering all numbers as negative.
2. Try setting it to INT_MAX and try again.  Note that this is the correct solution to the problem.

As another editorial remark, it's probably not a good idea to modify the dimensions of the array.  As declared in `main()` `m` is 50 by 50.  But you're effectively viewing it as 3 by 3 in `findRowWithMinimalSum()`.  That's not a good habit to get into, I can pretty much guarantee that doing so will cause problems for you at some point in the future.

Finally get yourself a debugger.  This would have jumped right off the screen at you if you'd single stepped through `findRowWithMinimalSum()` watching how the variables change as the program progresses.

Answer (score 0):

```
void findRowWithMinimalSum(int row, int col, int A[50][50])
{
  int i,j,sum=0,minSum=0,position,f=0;

 for(i=0; i<row; i++){
 printf("\nGive the elements of row %d:\n", i+1);
    for(j=0; j<col; j++)
scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);
  }

  for(i=0; i<row; i++){
  for(j=0; j<col; j++)
printf("%d ", A[i][j]);
  printf("\n");
 }

  for(i=0; i<row; i++){
  sum=0;
 for(j=0; j<col; j++){
sum = sum + A[i][j];
    }
    if(f==0)
    {
    minSum=sum;
 f++;
  }
 if(sum<minSum){
minSum = sum;
position = i;
    }
 }
 printf("\nThe row with minimal sum is %d whose sum is %d", position+1, minSum);
 }

int main(){
 int row, column, m[50][50];

//function call
indRowWithMinimalSum(3,3,m);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.